# Cytoscape installation and execution

Tags: java, windows-10, cytoscape

I have installed Cytoscape 3.8.0, but it doesn't run. However, I navigated to cytoscape.bat to check the issue which gave following error:

> Error: A JNI error has occurred, please check your installation and try again
> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.UnsupportedClassVersionError: org/cytoscape/launcher/internal/Launcher has been compiled by a more recent version of the Java Runtime (class file version 55.0), this version of the Java Runtime only recognizes class file versions up to 52.0

Also, after checking java version, I got following details:

```
java 11.0.8 2020-07-14 LTS
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment 18.9 (build 11.0.8+10-LTS)
```

I have also set all the required environment variables for java.

What can I do to resolve this issue?

Comment: You have to install Java 11.

Comment: @JCWasmx86 I have already installed java 11 (jdk 11.0.8), however my JRE version is 8,checked for JRE version 11 but I guess 8 is the latest version of JRE.

Answer (score 0):

As stated, you need to install Java 11.  Because of the license issues with Oracle JDK, we now test exclusively against OpenJDK.  You can get a version of OpenJDK 11 from [AdoptJDK](https://adoptopenjdk.net/)

Answer (score 0):

In addition to Java problems, a recent update on Mac has caused OpenCL based Cytoscape Apps to fail and prevents Cytoscape from launching.

This will be fixed in future updates, but you can fix your Mac installation immediately by disabling OpenCL by either of the two following methods:

- Download the [disable-opencl.dummy file](https://cytoscape.org/disable-opencl.dummy) to your CytoscapeConfiguration
  directory (in your user home directory).
- Or, you can create an empty dummy file by running this command in Terminal:

  `touch ~/CytoscapeConfiguration/disable-opencl.dummy`

These fixes are described at [Cytoscape.org](https://cytoscape.org/common_issues.html#opencl).